# which one is the correct option ? 1){$a_n$} is bounded and {$b_n$} is Bounded 2) atleast one of {$a_n$}, {$b_n$} is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given {$a_n$} ,{$b_n$} two monotone sequence  of real numbers and that  $\sum a_nb_n$ is convergent. Which one is the correct  option ?

1) {$a_n$} is  bounded and {$b_n$} is  bounded

2) At least one  of  {$a_n$}, {$b_n$}  is  bounded .

My attempts:  option is 1) that  correct option  take $a_n = b_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$,

option 2 is not correct  because take  $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$  and $b_n = n^2$,$\sum a_nb_n= \sum n$

Is  my answer correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is wrong. You have showed that option 1 *might* be true and you did not show anything concerning option 2, because the example you gave does not satisfy the assumptions.

Option 1 is not correct in general, since for $a_n = n $ and $b_n = e^{-n}$ we have $\sum_n a_n b_n $ convergent and $a_n$ unbounded.

Option 2 is correct. Since $\sum_n a_n b_n$ converges, one has $|a_nb_n| \to 0$. If both were unbounded then we would  not have $|a_nb_n|\to 0$. We are done.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is, **if** $\sum a_nb_n$ is bounded, which one **must** be true? In that case the answer is (2). It is easy to see that if they are both unbounded then (since they are monotone) so is $a_nb_n$, so the series does not converge.

An example to show that (1) is not always true is $a_n=n$ and $b_n=1/n^3$. In this case $a_n$ is unbounded, but $\sum a_nb_n=\sum 1/n^2$ converges.